# Missing } inserted when using \begin{matrix}

Tags: equations, matrices

I created following equation with an online generator, however it doesn't work on texmaker.

```
\begin{equation}
p_{ij}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\tau_{ij}^{\alpha}}{a\sum _{l\in N_{i}}\tau_{il}^{\alpha}} & if j \in N_{i}\\ 
0 & if j \notin N_{i}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}
```

I am trying type this equation: http://i.hizliresim.com/vgjvD4.gif

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matrix` environment requires

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in the document preamble. The error is not issued at `\begin{matrix}` because, for historical reasons, the command `\matrix` is defined in the LaTeX kernel.

However your usage of `matrix` is not the best for the case at hand; the `cases` environment is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p_{ij}=\begin{cases}
\frac{\tau_{ij}^{\alpha}}{a\sum _{l\in N_{i}}\tau_{il}^{\alpha}} &
  \text{if $j \in N_{i}$}\\ 
0 & \text{if $j \notin N_{i}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the usage of `\text` for properly printing “if”.

Possibly better is using `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p_{ij}=\begin{dcases*}
\frac{\tau_{ij}^{\alpha}}{a\sum _{l\in N_{i}}\tau_{il}^{\alpha}} &
  if $j \in N_{i}$\\ 
0 & if $j \notin N_{i}$
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `dcases` environment prints the entries in display style and the *-variant allows avoiding `\text` that's implicit.

This is the result of the latter code

[image]

to compare with the former

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I got error about `mathtools` : LaTeX Error: File `mathtools.sty' not found.